# access data from another content element in templavoila data structure

Tags: templates, data-structures, typo3, typoscript

I defined a page content element which has a background picture. It's a simple mapping on an attribtue with a wrap. Everything is working fine and the typoscript part of the data structure looks like this:

```
10 = IMG_RESOURCE
10.file.import = uploads/tx_templavoila/
10.file.import.current = 1
10.file.import.listNum = 0
10.stdWrap.wrap = background-image: url('|');
```

Now I have this same page containing tt_news on it to display a single view of a record. Defining a background picture would result in having this picture for each news entry which is not what I need. I want this now to use the first picture defined in a tt_news record.

is this possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using data, dataWrap, field and insertData to glue something together.

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing here, but try to use

```
plugin.tt_news.displaySingle.image.file
```

as your background-image url ... 
Besides a quick solution would be to change the type of a news entry to a internal page. This can be done for every news entry in its second dropdown box (type).